# Creating C++ DLL / COM

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, com, regsvr32

I am new to C++.

I wanted to create a C++ dll library which can be used by other PC as well. I tried creating a WIN32 Console Application with type setting to 'DLL'. I used to register dll with 'regsvr32' in order to use the dll in other PC.

1. Will I be able to use the compiled dll on other PC in this way? (Any steps I missed out?)
2. Is COM object also created in this way? If not, what else I need to do? (I saw C# use some kind of GUID(...)....)
3. Must I create a .h file for declaration in the dll project?

Comment: What makes you think that you need to create a COM DLL? What is your intended use case for this DLL? You don't need COM just to create a DLL that contains common code usable by multiple applications.

Comment: Your opening paragraph suggests you should learn a *lot* more about the structure of Windows applications, dynamic libraries, the things they have in common, and the things that set them apart. Learn about COM *after* that. Trying to learn about it before  hand (and making the mistake of using it where you don't need it) will only lead to a boat-load of frustration.

Comment: you mean the dll created can be used by other PC as well?

Comment: In a DLL you provide functions and/or (C++-)classes to be used by executables. COM is a mechanism (maybe even a paradigm) to distribute components (as COM stands for Component Object Model). This is rather different from pure DLLs. You should start with creating simple DLLs rather than with COM. Because as people said, COM is difficult to start with. Take a look [here](http://www.icynorth.com/development/createdlltutorial.html) to gain a basic understanding of DLLs.